# tkinter app i18n _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!text" after destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

i was building a app with tkinter ,and most of function it works.
it contains two frame, one for notebook function area, one for log area
there is lang switch combox in the notebook tab.
I was destroy all the frames and recreate after lang changes

```
import logging,os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import OptionMenu, filedialog,ttk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as ScrolledText



logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')        

# Add the handler to logger

logger = logging.getLogger()      


class TextHandler(logging.Handler):
    # This class allows you to log to a Tkinter Text or ScrolledText widget
    # Adapted from Moshe Kaplan: https://gist.github.com/moshekaplan/c425f861de7bbf28ef06

    def __init__(self, text):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        # Store a reference to the Text it will log to
        self.text = text
        self.max_length = 250


    def emit(self, record):
        msg = self.format(record)
        if len(msg) > self.max_length:
            lines = []
            while len(msg) > self.max_length:
                lines.append(msg[:self.max_length])
                msg = msg[self.max_length:]
            lines.append(msg)
            msg= '\n'.join(lines)

        def append():
            self.text.configure(state='normal')
            self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
            self.text.configure(state='disabled')
            # Autoscroll to the bottom
            self.text.yview(tk.END)
        # This is necessary because we can't modify the Text from other threads
        self.text.after(0, append)


def docView(frame,ttkframe,lang):
  
    
    sociallang = tk.StringVar()


    l_lang = tk.Label(ttkframe, text='display lang')
    # l_lang.place(x=10, y=90)
    l_lang.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 3, padx=14, pady=15)    


    keeplang = sociallang.get()    
    box = ttk.Combobox(ttkframe, textvariable=keeplang, state='readonly')
    # box.place(x=10, y=120)
    box.grid(row = 4, column = 1, columnspan = 3, padx=14, pady=15)    

    def selectedlang(event):
        box = event.widget
        
        print('selected lang is :',box.get())
        changeDisplayLang(box.get())
    box['values'] = ('en', 'zh')
    box.current(0)
    box.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", selectedlang)
def render(root,window,log_frame,lang):
    global doc_frame
    tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
    
    doc_frame = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    doc_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    doc_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="group1")
    doc_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="group1")
    doc_frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
    
    doc_frame_left = tk.Frame(doc_frame)
    doc_frame_left.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    doc_frame_right = tk.Frame(doc_frame)
    doc_frame_right.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew") 




    if lang=='en':
        print('1111')
        tab_control.add(doc_frame, text='help')
    else:
        tab_control.add(doc_frame, text='帮助')
        print('222')

    docView(doc_frame_left,doc_frame_right,lang)

    account_frame = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
    account_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    account_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1, uniform="group1")
    account_frame.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1, uniform="group1")
    account_frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)
    
    account_frame_left = tk.Frame(account_frame, height = 240)
    account_frame_left.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
    account_frame_right = tk.Frame(account_frame, height = 240)
    account_frame_right.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="nsew") 
    tab_control.add(account_frame, text='demo')
    docView(account_frame_right,account_frame_left,lang)

    # tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')
    tab_control.grid(row=0,column=0)








def start(lang):

    global ROOT_DIR
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
        os.path.abspath(__file__)
    )

    global root,paned_window,log_frame,mainwindow,st

    # root.resizable(width=True, height=True)
    root.iconbitmap("assets/icon.ico")
    # Create a PanedWindow widget (vertical)
    paned_window = tk.PanedWindow(root, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    paned_window.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    # Configure weights for mainwindow and log_frame
    paned_window.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=5)
    paned_window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Create the frame for the notebook
    mainwindow = ttk.Frame(paned_window)
    paned_window.add(mainwindow)
    mainwindow.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainwindow.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    


    log_frame =tk.Frame(paned_window)
    paned_window.add(log_frame)

    log_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    log_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    log_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    log_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)




    st = ScrolledText.ScrolledText(log_frame,                                      
                                # width = width, 
                                #     height = 5, 
                                    state='disabled')


    st.configure(font='TkFixedFont')
    st.grid(column=0, 
            row=0, 
            sticky='nwse',
            # columnspan=4
            )
    global text_handler
    text_handler = TextHandler(st)

    logger.addHandler(text_handler)    


    render(root,mainwindow,log_frame,lang)
    root.update_idletasks()

# # Set the initial size of the notebook frame (4/5 of total height)
    mainwindow_initial_percentage = 5 / 6  

    # Calculate the initial height of mainwindow based on the percentage
    initial_height = int(float(root.winfo_height()) * mainwindow_initial_percentage)
    mainwindow.config(height=initial_height)
    
def changeDisplayLang(lang):

    mainwindow.destroy()
    st.destroy()
    log_frame.destroy()
    paned_window.destroy()
    # root.quit()    
    # del text_handler
    start(lang)
    logger.info(f'switch lang to locale:{lang}')
    
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    start('en')
    root.mainloop()
```

what i want to is choose lang and refresh the whole app ,it do works but  give me

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wenke/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/wenke/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 814, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "/Users/wenke/github/app/t.py", line 40, in append
    self.text.configure(state='normal')
  File "/Users/wenke/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1646, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "/Users/wenke/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1636, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!panedwindow4.!frame2.!frame.!scrolledtext
```

Comment: `self.text.after(0, append)` should be inside function and add `self` to the `append(self`) function. This will  prevent an error.

Comment: This is telling you that you can't configure a widget after it has been destroyed.

Comment: @toyotaSupra That piece of the code looks alright to me. What do you mean? That statement is inside the method `emit` and it calls a local function `append` which has access to the variable `self` that is local inside `emit`.

Answer (score 1):

Use trap `try/except` will solve problem.

Snippet:

```
def append():
    try:
        self.text.configure(state='normal')
        self.text.insert(tk.END, msg + '\n')
        self.text.configure(state='disabled')
        # Autoscroll to the bottom
        self.text.yview(tk.END)
    except tk.TclError:
        pass
# This is necessary because we can't modify the Text from other threads
self.text.after(0, append)
```